# Error compiling app on emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

I'm trying to install my app into the emulator to prove it but when I try to start the app this crash and doesn't let me open

I'm using `CoordinarorLayout` in the `MainActivity`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="mx.com.dtss.carritocompras.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and in other activity I use a `CardView`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/img"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtDesPro"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtDetalle"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

this is what I've in my `AndroidManifest`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="mx.com.dtss.carritocompras" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>

and this is what I have in my `MainActivity`:

package mx.com.dtss.carritocompras;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recycler;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adap;
    ArrayList<elemento> listaCard;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recycler = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

        Thread tr = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
                String URL = "http://192.168.0.14/Publicacion/WebServiceCarrito.asmx";
                String METHOD_NAME = "listarProductos";
                String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/listarProductos";

                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet= true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                try{
                    transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    final SoapObject soap = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            listarProductos(soap);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e){

                }
            }
        };
        tr.start();
    }

    public void listarProductos(SoapObject soap){
        listaCard = new ArrayList<elemento>();
            for(int i = 0; i < soap.getPropertyCount(); i++){
                SoapObject reg = (SoapObject)soap.getProperty(i);
                elemento e1 = new elemento(reg.getProperty(0).toString(), reg.getProperty(1).toString(),
                        reg.getProperty(2).toString(), Double.parseDouble(reg.getProperty(4).toString()),
                        reg.getProperty(5).toString());

                listaCard.add(e1);
        }

        adap = new Adaptador(listaCard, getApplication());
        recycler.setAdapter(adap);
    }
}
```

And this is the error that throw me when I try to compile:

```
07-04 22:34:30.059 13691-13691/mx.com.dtss.carritocompras E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: mx.com.dtss.carritocompras, PID: 13691
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mx.com.dtss.carritocompras/mx.com.dtss.carritocompras.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2423)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5477)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                at mx.com.dtss.carritocompras.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6445)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5477) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                at mx.com.dtss.carritocompras.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6445) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5477) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/mx.com.dtss.carritocompras-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/mx.com.dtss.carritocompras-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mx.com.dtss.carritocompras-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mx.com.dtss.carritocompras-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mx.com.dtss.carritocompras-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mx.com.dtss.carritocompras-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mx.com.dtss.carritocompras-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mx.com.dtss.carritocompras-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mx.com.dtss.carritocompras-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mx.com.dtss.carritocompras-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mx.com.dtss.carritocompras-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/mx.com.dtss.carritocompras-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/mx.com.dtss.carritocompras-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                                                at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:583)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                at mx.com.dtss.carritocompras.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24) 
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6445) 
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5477) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView
                                                                                at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
```

I hope someone can help me

Comment: This is wrong in your XML  <android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView , change this with only recycler view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Logcat says that there is error on `line 10` which is

```
 <android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.app.AlertController.RecycleListView>
```

Instead of this use below

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Answer (score 1):

`RecycleListView` is an internal class not intended for external use. The fact that it is showing up publicly in the support library is probably a mistake.

Use this code in your xml file to create a ListView

```
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```